# How do I use the pre processor classes in thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Hello I am wanting to create my own dialect. For instance an `employee` dialect. There should be a processor `employee:status`, which is just a selection box:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
    <option th:each="status : ${T(com.test.employee.EmployeeStatus).values()}" th:text="${status}"></option>
</select>
```

But as you can see I am making use of Thymeleaf expressions here, and I have more complicated bits of HTML I would like to encapsulate into my custom dialect. But how do I use Thymeleaf dialects within my dialect ? As confusing as that sounds.

I am having a very difficult time finding examples and tutorials on extending Thymeleaf. Are there examples of including fragments, or bits of HTML with thymleaf attributes in custom processors? That's what ideally I would like to do.

Comment: I did not understand what is your problem here but for preprocessing thymeleafe use `__${anyvariable}__`.

Comment: You can create your own Dialect extending org.thymeleaf.dialect.AbstractProcessorDialect I can give you a example if that you after

Comment: @TanmoyMandal What do you mean by anyvariable? Looks interesting.

Comment: @TanmoyMandal Do you know how to add context variables in a thymeleaf doProcess method? That is something else I want to know how to do?

Comment: not sure what you are after but this might help you.
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/sayhelloagainextendingthymeleafevenmore5minutes.html